# Retrieving multiple values from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that returns multiple values as results of complex math.

```
var getData = function () {
var a=Math.somethingReallyDifficultToCalculate
var b=Math.anotherDifficultThingToCalculate
return {a: a, b: b}
}
```

and I then want to retrieve the data like so:

```
var result = getData()
console.log(result.a,result.b)
```

Will my program run the entire function both times or will var result only retain the values? Will the result be cached? 
In case this code will run the function twice, what would be a good way to keep the values and not the reference itself?

I know I can use:

```
var result = $.extend({},getData())
```

which I know will only keep the values and not the reference but is this the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: looks like it will calc them every time. there is no cache here, though you can set one up.

Comment: @dandavis seems you are not correct. check out this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/MichaelSel/03nprumv/

Comment: 'result' is an object with two values. Your function will only run when you call getData(), not when you access values within 'result'.

Comment: If you wanted to call the function two times you might call: console.log(getData().a, getData().b)

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood and thought you were asking about `Math.somethingReallyDifficultToCalculate`, the result of which is not cached inside the function in the first code box. if you cache the function return, then it will run just once (it doesn't matter where plain data comes from once it's there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only run the function once.

Once you do this:

```
var result = getData();
```

... the `getData()` function has done its job.

Advice: You should terminate statements using semicolons (`;`). If you do not use them then Javascript will automatically insert them, and that can cause all kinds of unexpected problems.

Comment: What about 
console.log(getData().a, getData().b)?

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich When you see the `()` thing, it means that a function is being called. So, the function will be called twice in that example.

Comment: so who's right? You or dandavis which also has a lot of reputation and says exactly the opposite?

Comment: it seems you were right. Check out the console. 
https://jsfiddle.net/MichaelSel/03nprumv/

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich Well, he is wrong. He may have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score -1):

Why you not trying using object oriented notations

like this.

```
var getData = {
    a : null,
    b : null,
    c: null,
    setVal : function(){
        this.a = Math.somethingReallyDifficultToCalculate;
        this.b = Math.anotherDifficultThingToCalculate;
        this.c = 10;
    },
    getVal : function(){
        return {a: this.a, b: this.b,c:this.c};
    }
};

getData.setVal()
var result = getData.getVal()
```

Everytime you call **getVal** you get saved values and if you want to alter the value call **setVal**.

Also you can pass parameter to set the values while calling **setVal** which is the best way.

So final code like this,

```
var getData = {
    a : null,
    b : null,
    c: null,
    setVal : function(a,b,c){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    },
    getVal : function(){
        return {a: this.a, b: this.b,c:this.c};
    }
};

var a = Math.somethingReallyDifficultToCalculate;
var b = Math.anotherDifficultThingToCalculate;

getData.setVal(a,b,30)
var result = getData.getVal()
```

Comment: What does this have to do with anything?

Comment: This is *ludicrously* overcomplicated for just trying to return two values from one function. If I saw someone writing code like this at work, I'd make them rewrite it.

Comment: returning two value means you are returning one Object and not two values.Please check the code posted in questions.Can you please explain me how will you rewrite the code?Please share the fiddle

Comment: The way the OP has written it is already perfectly fine. There's no need to rewrite it.